# Spring PointCut Annotation method call is called after the Actual business method

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-annotations

We are using Spring AOP pointCutAdvice with the `AnnotationMatchingPointcut`.

sometimes, the actual method is called before the `PointCutAdvice` is called. And later again the same Actual method is called (totally twice).

Are there any chances of happening like this.

**Note**: Don't have a test case to prove currently and i cannot paste the original code for some obvious reasons.

Comment: It's shot in dark at best with the minimal information shared. Although the complete original code isn't expected a simple [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would help.

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond, 
My issue is resolved as the problem is not due to the PointCutAdvice, instead it is due to the Singleton bean which is mixing when the same process runs in 2 different threads, after making the bean as Prototype, the issue is resovled